# Find my play store app in my mobile play store

Tags: android, publish

I have publish my first app on play store. The status display published but i cant find that app in my play store of mobile. How can I search my app in mobile play store device

Comment: search with your company name

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to search for the package name of your app. So search for `com.yourname.yourapp` or whatever your package name is. Also realize that it can take several hours for the app to appear in the store after you hit publish.

You should also try finding it in the play store in a web browser. You can find it by going to: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yourname.yourapp -- where the last part is your specific package name.

Comment: current status display published and also unable to find from package name

Comment: How long ago did you publish the app? It will say "published" even when it's not in the store yet.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how long ago you published it, you simply just may not be able to see it yet. Even if you can see it by clicking "view in Play Store" on the developer console, chances are it's still not visible to people searching for it organically (including yourself). Wait for a few hours (mine usually take around 4-5 hours) and then search for your developer name, not that app name. That's what I do.

New apps usually won't even show up in the search results until you get a few downloads and the Play Store "recognizes" your app.

Answer (score 0):

1. Login Google Play Developer Console https://play.google.com/apps/publish
2. View all applications
3. Click the application you want the store link for
4. On the top you will see App Title, Logo and Class name, in same area you will see a link "View in App Store".

This is the link you can use to locate your app.