# android app found on web playstore but not on mobile app play store

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have the mobile application published on google play store with title `Visual Pro`. I am able to search app on playstore website, but when searched on playstore in a mobile device, it's not listed there.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096811/find-my-play-store-app-in-my-mobile-play-store?rq=1)

Comment: Does your app contain play store filters?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354065/app-not-in-search-results-on-google-play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the new application won't even show up in the search results until you get a few downloads and the Play Store "recognizes" your app.

You have to wait for the minimum for 4-5 hours or you can suggest your friends download that app so it will visible in google indexing.

Please check **[Making Your App Content Searchable by Google](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/)**, It will help you to understand google play store search indexing.

Also, you can check more info to [here](https://www.quora.com/My-app-is-not-showing-on-Play-Store-when-I-search-it-by-its-name) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354065/app-not-in-search-results-on-google-play).

Hope this will help you!